# how can i access openVPN to a VPN Provider

Tags: openvpn

How can I open with a connection to a vpn vpn provider build. 
I have the Netherlands_B.ovpn file and ca.crt. 
What is the command? openvpn - config Netherlands_B.ovpn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty 4 your ansther but, find a soliton. the config file  ovpn have a nother file ca file.... 
Only copy both files in the openvpn direktory and type openvpn --config Netherlands_B.ovpn it works, befor i copie only the config file

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
The command:

```
openvpn --config Netherlands_B.ovpn
```

run as root should connect you to your vpn provider as all the information openvpn requires is stored in this file.

If it fails have a look in the Netherlands_B.ovpn file. since its a clear text configuration file you can simply edit it. 
Check that the required certificates and keys are in the path specified in the file.